# How to define a QDir in pyside for QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside

I would like to open a file dialog using

```
fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QtCore.QDir("/home/user"))
```

but this expresssion gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(ImageViewer, str, PySide.QtCore.QDir)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(PySide.QtGui.QWidget = None, unicode = QString(), unicode = QString(), unicode = QString(), PySide.QtCore.QString = QString(), PySide.QtGui.QFileDialog.Options = 0)
```

The documentation is useless here, as documentation only prominently exists for Qt for C++ (maybe there is some hidden documentation for pyside...?). And since the data types are a little different between C++ and python, I am not able to solve my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the [pyside documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QFileDialog.html)

Comment: Examples of absolute paths:

QDir("/home/user/Documents")
QDir("C:/Documents and Settings")
but this does not work for my problem!

Comment: `QDir` is not in the list of supported signatures. So i assume you should pass it as a string.

Comment: Yes, that works. But it is not obvious from the 'standard' Qt documentation..., thanks

Comment: @Alex 'standard' PySide documentation is here http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/ - the link to the documentation can be found on pyside home page here http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide and it is not hidden!

Answer (score 0):

http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/ Documentation for PySide.

look in the static functions section. http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QFileDialog.html

```
parent = None # QtGui.QMainWindow()
filters = "All File (*);;CSV (*.csv *.CSV)" # Only allow these file ext to be opened
title = "Save As"
open_at = "directory/"
results = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent, title, open_at, filters)
```

The QtCore.QDir is an object. It wants unicode / str. So just use "/home/user".

```
"/home/user"
or
QtCore.QDir("/home/user").absolutePath() # This ensures that the given location exists.
```

Comment: please update the link to the documentation, it should be http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/ - thanks